# How to move compressed TSV files from Google Cloud Bucket to Big Query with auto detect schema?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, data-pipeline

I have been trying multiple ways to move the compressed TSV to Big query. I was able to get the command working but didn't see any table being loaded. Please help me figure out to write the command that works.

bq ‘--project_id’ --nosync load --source_format CSV --field_delimiter ‘\t’ --autodetect --skip_leading_rows ‘0’ --quote=‘’ --encoding UTF-8 :table.destinationtable ‘gs://bucketname/filename.tsv.gz’

Successfully started load 162822:bqjob_r2d00a5817904935f_0000015c79e61b7c_1

Comment: What do you mean that you "didn't see any table being loaded"? Loading isn't instantaneous, so you need to check the status of the job to see when it finishes.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I was waiting for a while to check the destination table and it was not having any values.

Comment: You need to [check the status of the load job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get). You can use the "Try this API" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I tried the API, got the error message below. 
{"reason": "invalid",
    "location": "gs:///<bucket_name</<file_name>.tsv.gz",
    "message": "Could not parse 'ibcx' as int for field int64_field_5 (position 5) starting at location 3743224 "
   }

Comment: Okay, so now you have a pointer to the problem that you need to fix before trying again. Alternatively, you can set the [`configuration.load.maxBadRecords` property](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.maxBadRecords).

Comment: Does this error message mean the tsv file has data formatting issues or an extra tab in some row? How can that be handled while importing?

Comment: Check the other configuration options for jagged rows, etc. It sounds like you just have a bad value in a row in this case.

Comment: I tried both, --max_bad_records and --allow_jagged_rows. The load operation ran for a while and I got error  "status": {
  "state": "DONE",
  "errorResult": {
   "reason": "internalError",
   "message": "An internal error has occurred"
  },
  "errors": [
   {
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "An internal error has occurred"
   }
  ]
 },
 "statistics": {
  "creationTime": "1497382116337",
  "startTime": "1497382116976",
  "endTime": "1497382817991"
 },

Comment: This looks like a bug, so consider [posting a bug on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with a job ID and someone can look into it.